# How to submit fields marked as OPTIONS to jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1

Tags: yodlee

The [documentation listed](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addSiteAccount1) only specifies how to submit the following field typeNames:

- IF_LOGIN
- IF_PASSWORD

We are having a problem submitting user details that make use of the typeName OPTIONS.

Here is the siteInfo for St. George, which uses the siteId 12099, retrieved via jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/getSiteInfo

```
array (
    'popularity' => 0,
    'siteId' => 12099,
    'orgId' => 6930,
    'defaultDisplayName' => 'St. George Bank (Australia)',
    'defaultOrgDisplayName' => 'St.George Bank',
    'contentServiceInfos' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'contentServiceId' => 14551,
            'siteId' => 12099,
            'containerInfo' => 
            array (
                'containerName' => 'bank',
                'assetType' => 1,
            ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'contentServiceId' => 15662,
            'siteId' => 12099,
            'containerInfo' => 
            array (
                'containerName' => 'bill_payment',
                'assetType' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
            'contentServiceId' => 14738,
            'siteId' => 12099,
            'containerInfo' => 
            array (
                'containerName' => 'credits',
                'assetType' => 2,
            ),
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
            'contentServiceId' => 14839,
            'siteId' => 12099,
            'containerInfo' => 
            array (
                'containerName' => 'insurance',
                'assetType' => 2,
            ),
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
            'contentServiceId' => 14840,
            'siteId' => 12099,
            'containerInfo' => 
            array (
                'containerName' => 'loans',
                'assetType' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'enabledContainers' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'containerName' => 'bank',
            'assetType' => 1,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'containerName' => 'bill_payment',
            'assetType' => 0,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
            'containerName' => 'credits',
            'assetType' => 2,
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
            'containerName' => 'insurance',
            'assetType' => 2,
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
            'containerName' => 'loans',
            'assetType' => 2,
        ),
    ),
    'baseUrl' => 'http://www.stgeorge.com.au/',
    'loginForms' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'conjunctionOp' => 
            array (
                'conjuctionOp' => 1,
            ),
            'componentList' => 
            array (
                0 => 
                array (
                    'valueIdentifier' => 'LOGIN',
                    'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
                    'fieldType' => 
                    array (
                        'typeName' => 'IF_LOGIN',
                    ),
                    'size' => 20,
                    'maxlength' => 19,
                    'name' => 'LOGIN',
                    'displayName' => 'Card/Access Number',
                    'isEditable' => true,
                    'isOptional' => false,
                    'isEscaped' => false,
                    'helpText' => '76368',
                    'isOptionalMFA' => false,
                    'isMFA' => false,
                ),
                1 => 
                array (
                    'valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD',
                    'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
                    'fieldType' => 
                    array (
                        'typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
                    ),
                    'size' => 20,
                    'maxlength' => 6,
                    'name' => 'PASSWORD',
                    'displayName' => 'Security Number',
                    'isEditable' => true,
                    'isOptional' => false,
                    'isEscaped' => false,
                    'helpText' => '76369',
                    'isOptionalMFA' => false,
                    'isMFA' => false,
                ),
                2 => 
                array (
                    'valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD1',
                    'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
                    'fieldType' => 
                    array (
                        'typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
                    ),
                    'size' => 20,
                    'maxlength' => 12,
                    'name' => 'PASSWORD1',
                    'displayName' => 'Internet Password',
                    'isEditable' => true,
                    'isOptional' => false,
                    'isEscaped' => false,
                    'helpText' => '76370',
                    'isOptionalMFA' => false,
                    'isMFA' => false,
                ),
                3 => 
                array (
                    'validValues' => 
                    array (
                        0 => '1',
                        1 => '2',
                        2 => '3',
                        3 => '4',
                    ),
                    'displayValidValues' => 
                    array (
                        0 => '1',
                        1 => '2',
                        2 => '3',
                        3 => '4',
                    ),
                    'valueIdentifier' => 'OPTION',
                    'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
                    'fieldType' => 
                    array (
                        'typeName' => 'OPTIONS',
                    ),
                    'size' => 20,
                    'maxlength' => 40,
                    'name' => 'OPTION',
                    'displayName' => 'Issue Number',
                    'isEditable' => true,
                    'isOptional' => false,
                    'isEscaped' => false,
                    'helpText' => '75331',
                    'isOptionalMFA' => false,
                    'isMFA' => false,
                ),
            ),
            'defaultHelpText' => 'login url chaged because site support new login url',
        ),
    ),
    'isHeld' => false,
    'isCustom' => false,
    'siteSearchVisibility' => true,
)
```

Using the above site information, this is what we are passing to /jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'enclosedType' => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
    'credentialFields.enclosedType' => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
    'siteId' => '12099',
    'credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier' => 'LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].size' => '20', 
    'credentialFields[0].name' => 'LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].displayName' => 'Card/Access Number',
    'credentialFields[0].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[0].value' => 'field1',
    'credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].size' => '20', 
    'credentialFields[1].name' => 'PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].displayName' => 'Security Number',
    'credentialFields[1].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[1].value' => 'field2',
    'credentialFields[2].valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD1',
    'credentialFields[2].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[2].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[2].size' => '20', 
    'credentialFields[2].name' => 'PASSWORD1',
    'credentialFields[2].displayName' => 'Internet Password',
    'credentialFields[2].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[2].value' => 'field3',
    'credentialFields[3].valueIdentifier' => 'OPTION',
    'credentialFields[3].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[3].fieldType.typeName' => 'OPTIONS',
    'credentialFields[3].size' => '20', 
    'credentialFields[3].name' => 'OPTION',
    'credentialFields[3].displayName' => 'Issue Number',
    'credentialFields[3].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[3].value' => '1',
)
```

Unfortunately, we are receiving the following response:

```
array (
    'errorOccurred' => 'true',
    'exceptionType' => 'com.yodlee.core.IncompleteArgumentException',
    'referenceCode' => '_4d346818-524f-4583-a5db-2f58b0c8fd2c',
    'message' => 'OPTIONS',
)
```

Can someone please supply a working example of the data format we should be using for field's of typeName = OPTIONS.

Can you please update the API or documentation to explicitly mention that the form information revealed in getSiteInfo and searchSite are incompatible with addSiteAccount1.

What is the reason for returning malformed fields?

Should we be rewriting all fields named 'OPTION' to 'OPTIONS', or is this unique to siteId 12099?

Would a field named 'OPTION1' need to be renamed to 'OPTIONS1'; similar to the existing pattern used for LOGIN and PASSWORD fields?

Answer (score 0):

- Please use [getSiteLoginForm](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteLoginForm) for getting the login form info for any site.
- Use the login form info from above to construct the addSiteAccount request.

The sample you provided is correct , it's just that pass the below parameter as indicated.

> credentialFields[3].name' => 'OPTIONS'

It should work for you. Also please remove below parameter form request as it's duplicating and not complete

```
 'enclosedType' => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
```